# What is the equation for this table of value?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering about how to solve this question(Linear Relations)

We got this table

Time is in front of  the Cost

2  in front of 22.00

4   in front of 32.00

6   in front of 42.00

8   in front of 52.00

the question is( Find the initial value and the rate of change and what is the equation?)

I know that the initial value is 22 and the rate of change is 5 because 10/2 = 5

and when I wrote the equation was like this C=22+5t

I tested this equation with all numbers but it does not work!

so what is the right equation? or is there anything wrong with my answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer is also how I would do it, however if you want to compare to your teacher's method, here is another way.

Your method was fine except you got the initial value wrong. The initial value is the value at $t=0$.

You know the slope is $5$ and the value at $t=2$ is $22$.

So going back 1 step means at $t=1$, we have $C=22-5=17$.

Going back one more step, at $t=0$ we have $C=17-5=12$.

So the initial value is $12$, not $22$. So your equation becomes $C=12+5t$, which is correct and also agrees with the other answer.

Comment: I got the right idea now...I did not pay a close attention to it, I followed the teacher's way without thinking of anything else. Thank you all for assisting me

Comment: @MustafaAhmed No problem :) After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it (either mine or coffeemath's answer, whichever you think was more helpful). This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Comment: I did that, I was about to do it for sure, you all are doing a very good job.

Answer (score 0):

The slope is $\Delta y/ \Delta x=10/2=5.$ This means an equation can be $(y-22)=5(x-2
).$ If you want to, that could be multiplied out to get $y=5x+c$ form. That gives $y=5x+12.$ So in your $C$ variable it's $C=12+5t,$ not much different from what you got.

Comment: Yes, I see now, this is different from what I have taught from my teacher

Comment: C is for cost and t for time or number of hours or minutes. So the equation would be this C=22+5t and that's why it does not match with my number of hours

Comment: The equation $y-y_1-m(x-x_1)$ is the so-called "point-slope" form of a (nonvertical) line. Probably could google it...,

Comment: I got it now, I should have gone back one step, such as how did we get 22 in first, so C=12+5t = C=12+5(2) equal 22